# How to use multiple transactions in Snowflake Task?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have two ETL jobs running on a stream I've created on a table. I need to run both on the same stream data and I read that in order to do so the DML statements (in my case merge statements) need to be wrapped in a transaction and committed at the end. I can't seem to be able to do that in a task though. I think I'm messing the semi-colon somewhere. This is what I've tried

```
create or replace task my_task as
begin;
  merge into my_table1 t using my_stream s on t.id=s.id when matched insert values (id, col1);

  merge into my_table2 t using my_stream s on t.id=s.id when matched insert values (id, col2);
commit;
```

This is just an example, the merge statements do more complex stuff.

The script just runs up to `begin` if I use a semi-colon or get an EOF error if I don't use one even though I have multiple semi-colons later in the script (so it tries to read past `commit`)

Comment: Hi - if you read the documentation it clearly states that a task can run a single SQL statement or a stored procedure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The task can call a stored procedure that contains the different statements within a transaction:

```sql
create procedure ...
    as
    $$
        ...
        statement1;

        BEGIN TRANSACTION;
        statement2;
        COMMIT;

        statement3;
        ...

    $$;
```

- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/transactions.html

Answer (score 0):

Yeah - I've just hit this. Lots of googling blind alleys trying to find how to start a transaction in a task. Not helped by the overloading of the word 'BEGIN' to mean:

1. Begin transaction
2. Begin task definition

I finally got this working (after sleeping on it) with:

```
create or replace task MyTask ...
as
    declare uuid varchar(38);
begin
    uuid := uuid_string();
    call audit_log('blah', :uuid);

    begin transaction;             --- this is key
    insert into target
    select * from MyStream where rectype = 'Shares'; -- specific query

    insert into toarget
    select * from MyStream where rectype = 'Cash'; -- different complex query

    commit transaction;

end;
```